# z-index issue in "Review First Post"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, design

When scrolling, the guide gets `fixed` position.

There is an issue with `z-index` so the box is going under the post's `textarea`

[image: screen record]

Comment: Bug report on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344041

Comment: @double-beep Liked the infinite loop :)

Comment: For me the guidance of how to write questions on the right overflows the page footer.

Comment: Temporarily fixed with my userscript [ReviewQueueHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js)

Comment: This is also the case for the green text of changed texts https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394567/review-suggested-edits-queue-ui-error-changed-text-scrolls-over-buttons

Comment: @SamuelLiew status-review pls?

Comment: If interested, I solved it by adding `.js-review-bar { z-index: 999; }` to the CSS I use for my personal adjustments. There's probably a number which is more "appropriate" within the `z-index` values which SE uses, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boy howdy this bug is older than I thought. Sorry about that.

The fix is in the queue for deployment to production.