# Review Suggested Edits Queue UI error - changed text scrolls over buttons

Tags: bug, review-queues, user-interface

I was busy in the review edits queue and scrolled down on an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25575675) when my buttons dissapeared behind the changed text:

> [image: dissapearing buttons]

Comment: no, this is a different UI element having a z-index issue

Comment: look at the linked questions in that question and you will see a lot of them reporting the same issue related to z-index. Even if it's a different element, the main issue is the same: we need to fix the z-index in many places on the review queue

Comment: hmmh, I see, it might be a general issue then that can be fixed quickly