# Add z-index for better readability while scrolling Review Late Answer (review bar)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I have suggestion regarding better user readability. While Scrolling down the page, review bar (anchor bar) on Late review which is front stack element and lower stack element looks same and displaying on each other. 
Seeing in Opera 67.0.3575.53 and have not reviewed in Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Issue]

My suggestion: I think, front stack element should have greater than lower stack element. I mean, if we have `z-index: 100;` to class `js-review-bar s-card mb24 p0` might fix the issue or any other way work around would be fine as well. It doesn't necessary have to be same as what I've suggested.

[image: Fixed]
[image: Fixed1]

Comment: Same problem as this (albeit a different queue): [z-index issue in "Review First Post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394159/z-index-issue-in-review-first-post)