# Issue with z-index by scrolling on the Review | Low quality post

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

I found this small bug when you scroll in the "Review Low quality post" page. The recommendations are shown over the popup that appears after I clicked on the "Recommend Deletion" button.

[image]

Comment: (A solution just for you: If you know some CSS, inspect the popup and modify its code to z-index: 2; for example!)

Comment: This is also happening in Late Answers. I'd expect it's so for all the queues.

Comment: seems like they didn't *really* fix the it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394159/8620333